# Django REST ViewSet ordering for Null-able columns

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Consider a table Person:

```
| name | wealth |
|------| ------ |
|Abby  | 12     |
|Ben   | Null   |
|Carl  | 5      |
|Diane | Null   |
```

We want to sort the rows by wealth, descending, i.e. to get `(Abby, Carl, Ben, Diane)`, but Django's `order_by` function sorts them by Null first:

```
class PersonViewSet(serializers.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = PersonSerializer
        queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('-wealth)
```

gives `(Ben, Diane, Abby, Carl)`, i.e. it first lists the Null values then sorts by wealth.

---

I tried redefining the `get_queryset` method:

```
class PersonViewSet(serializers.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def get_queryset():
        invalid_entries = Person.objects.filter(wealth=None)
        valid_entries = Person.objects.all().difference(invalid_entries).order_by('-wealth')
        return valid_entries.union(invalid_entries)
```

This does return the desired behavior, `(Abby, Carl, Ben, Diane)` but messes up the detail view, and gives the `get() returned multiple values` error.

---

Is there a way to get the desired behavior, by customizing the ordering functionality, or modifying `get_queryset` *only* for the list view?

Comment: you need something like this https://gist.github.com/shulcsm/a9899d39c7d7bb5ada5e in Postgres SQL this can be expressed as `ORDER BY wealth DESC NULLS LAST`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/) of `django 1.11`

> Added the nulls_first and nulls_last parameters to Expression.asc()
>   and desc() to control the ordering of null values.

So, If you are using `django>=1.11`, you can `Expression.desc()` method to sort your fields as below,

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by(F('wealth').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Comment: perfect, this is what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063017/8563165) answer.
You can also define [Options.ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#ordering) attribute inside your view class:

```
class PersonViewSet(serializers.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    ordering = [F('wealth').desc(nulls_last=True)]
```